# How can I centre 2 <div>s?

Tags: html, css

How can I centre the two `<div>`s within the `<hero>` div?
[Here is my codepen](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/GWOEPv).

Just to make things more clear, I want to the photo of me and the grey rectangle shape in the centre over the background image.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="shape"></div>
  <div class="shape2">
      <p>kjjjjjjjjjkjjjkkjkj</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
}
.shape {
  content:url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
  border-radius: 25px;
  background:grey;
  color:white;
  padding:3px;
  margin:200px auto 0 auto;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.shape2 {
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #4D5061, #4D5061);
  border-radius: 85px;
  color:white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding:0px;
  margin:410px auto 0 auto;
  width:250px;
  height:40px;
  left:200;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Liam Docherty Digital Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
 <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> 
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
                    <h1 class="nav-title">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>


    <section id="section1" class="section1">
      <div class="hero">
          <div class="shape"></div>
          <div class="shape2">
              <p>kjjjjjjjjjkjjjkkjkj</p>
          </div>
        </div>





      <a href="#section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>
    <section id="section2" class="section2">


      <a href="#contact-me"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>

    <section id="contact-me" class="contact_section section3">


      <a href="#section1"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        <h2 class="footertext">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h2>
    </div>
 </footer>     
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #4D5061;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}
.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
}
.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-menu li { 
    text-align:center 
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #4D5061;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}
.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}
.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.nav-title {
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin:0;
  top: 35px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
#logo {
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.hero {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  height: 95vh;
}
.section1 {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.section2 {
  background-color: #11B5E4;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.section3 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.fa-angle-down {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.fa-angle-up {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
.footer {
  height: 6vh;
  background-color: #4D5061;
  padding:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
.footertext{
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.shape {
  content:url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
  border-radius: 25px;
  background:grey;
  color:white;
  padding:3px;
  margin:200px auto 0 auto;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.shape2 {
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #4D5061, #4D5061);
  border-radius: 85px;
  color:white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding:0px;
  margin:410px auto 0 auto;
  width:250px;
  height:40px;
  left:200;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap `.shape, .shape2` in a new element, absolutely position that new element to center it horizontally/vertically, then center the 2 shape elements within that element.

```
.shapes {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  position: absolute;
}
.shape, .shape2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: #4D5061;
  height: 10vh;
  z-index: 100;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: right;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  text-align: center
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #4D5061;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14pt;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 9px;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.nav.navbar-nav,
.nav.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-title {
  font-size: 14pt;
  margin: 0;
  top: 35px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
.navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#logo {
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.hero {
  background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 95vh;
}

.section1 {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.section2 {
  background-color: #11B5E4;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.section3 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.fa-angle-down {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.fa-angle-up {
  color: #4D5061;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.footer {
  height: 6vh;
  background-color: #4D5061;
  padding: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.footertext {
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.shape {
  content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.shape2 {
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #4D5061, #4D5061);
  border-radius: 85px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 250px;
}

.shapes {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
}

.shape,
.shape2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <html lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Liam Docherty Digital Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
        <h1 class="nav-title">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h1>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>


  <section id="section1" class="section1">
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="shapes">
        <div class="shape"></div>
        <div class="shape2">
          <p>kjjjjjjjjjkjjjkkjkj</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <a href="#section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

  </section>
  <section id="section2" class="section2">


    <a href="#contact-me"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

  </section>

  <section id="contact-me" class="contact_section section3">


    <a href="#section1"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <h2 class="footertext">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h2>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If the user decreases or enlarges the view within their browser will your way of coding this make the <div> shapes stay in place? If so I'll take that as the answer.

Comment: @NorthDown It will put those 2 shapes in the horizontal/vertical center of `.hero`. It references %'s, so it isn't a pixel value. As long as `.hero` scales with the browser, the `.shape` element I added will scale relative to `.hero`

Answer (score 0):

With `.hero`, add `text-align: center;` as a property.

Like so:

```
.hero{
    background-image: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position:relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 70vh;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And remove `position: absolute` from each element :)

Comment: Your correct. However, if I remove `absolute` this will dramatically affect my whole site. Here is my [codepen.](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/ZeaJrb).

Answer (score 0):

remove position element from hero, shape and shape2 class. then add

```
position:relative
```

to section1 class. then reduce the top margin of shape2 class. all that stuff at the bottom, the section2 and contact stuff with the arrows also seems off. It needs some tinkering as well

Comment: Your correct. However, if I remove `absolute` this will dramatically affect my whole site. Here is my [codepen.](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/ZeaJrb).

Answer (score 0):

Change the margin of the .shape into

```
margin:200px auto 0 550px;
```

then change the margin of the .shape2 into

```
margin:410px auto 0 525px;
```

It will solve the problem however it`s not that responsive

Comment: Thanks for your time, awarded you the answer. How can I move                     `<h1 class="nav-title">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h1>` to the left?
Would it be possible you could help me with this?

Comment: but with a hard coded left margin, on a lot of screens it wouldn't be centered

Comment: and if you want to move the h1 left, remove the text-align:center from the css

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

to .hero

Answer (score 0):

One technique to center abosolute positioned element is to add left: 50% and margin-left: negative 50% of the widht.

For example your shape:

```
.shape {      content:url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
  border-radius: 25px;
  background:grey;
  color:white;
  padding:3px;
  margin:200px auto 0 auto;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

width is 200px so we add margin-left: -100px and left: 50%;

here is the fork of your codepen: http://codepen.io/adrianrios/pen/ZeaaNN